# How to setup an install path with the IBM Spark installer?

Tags: apache-spark

The IBM installer for Apache Spark, in my case IBM_Spark_DK_2.1.0.0_Linux_s390x.bin offers the following options to execute the installer (the option list is shorten by me to make it more readable):

```
Usage: IBM_Spark_DK_2.1.0.0_Linux_s390x [-f <path_to_installer_properties_file> | -options]

where options include:
    -i [swing | console | silent]
            specify the user interface mode for the installer
    -D<name>=<value>  
            specify installer properties
```

I want to run the installer in silent mode and I want to specify an install path. I assume that the path can be passed be the -D option but I can not find out which `name` this should be.

Does any one know these options or is there somewhere a little bit more verbose documentation I have missed to read?

Bottom line: what would I need to use for xxxx in the following line?

```
IBM_Spark_DK_2.1.0.0_Linux_s390x.bin -i silent -Dxxxx=/my/install/path
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:

```
IBM_Spark_DK_2.1.0.0_Linux_s390x.bin -i silent -f <pathToInstallerPropertiesFile/InstallerPropertiesFile.cfg>
```

As a start you can put into this file these options (change to your needs):

```
USER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/spark
INSTALLER_JDK_HOME=/opt/ibm/java-s390x-80
INSTALL_DRIVE_ROOT=/tmp
```

The funny thing is that I could not find a documentation for a list of options. But once installed you can find under `$USER_INSTALL_DIR/_uninstall/` a properties file `installvariables.properties` which lists plenty of options you can use with the installer. I have not checked if you can use them all, from that point you are on your own. Have fun!